# jQuery/PHP File Upload Times Out Before Loading Next Page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image-uploading

So I am developing the following image upload script, based off an existing open-source script. It's currently viewable live here: http://images.oneightynyc.com/

Now if you take any series of regular sized images (under 5mb) and proceed to upload them, the upload process goes just fine. Uploads the files, and brings you to a page that displays the link codes to those files. However let's say you upload a few large images, like the following:

http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d90/img/sample/pic_005b.jpg

http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d90/img/sample/pic_003b.jpg

The uploads happen in the process, however the script never brings you to the uploaded page. The only way I am aware that the upload has actually taken place is if I browse to the Gallery page and see that the files are listed there.

Here is the uploader.php file which handles the upload:

```
<?
//ob_start();
session_start();
$auth_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
if (!$auth_id || empty($auth_id) || $auth_id==""){
$auth_id = 0;
}
require_once("config.php"); 
require_once("limits.php"); 
require_once("ftp.class.php");
require_once("func.php"); 

$link = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password) or die("Could not connect to the database.");

mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Could not select the database.");

if ($config[Uploads] == 0) {

$msg= "<center><b><br><br><br>Uploads are temporarily disabled by the site admin</center></b>";
}

else if ($config[Uploads] == 1 && !$auth_id) {

$msg= "<center><b><br><br><br>You have to <a href=\"register.php\" title=\"Register\">Register</a> before you will be able to upload photos.</center></b>";
}


$query = "select count(*) as total from ftp where status=1";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed.");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{

$total=$row[total];
}


if($total<=0)

    {

    $no_server="1";

    $ftpid=0;

    $url=$server_url."/images/";

    }

else

{

$query = "select * from ftp where status=1 ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed.");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 

    {

            $no_server="0";

        $ftpid=$row['ftpid'];

        $path=$row['name'];        

        $url=$row['dir'];        

        $host=$row['host'];        

        $user=$row['user'];        

        $pass=$row['ftppass'];        

    }    

 }

// get variables for fields on upload screen                

        $tos = $_POST['tos'];        

        $prv = $_POST['prv'];        

                if($prv!="1")

                $prv=0;



        $uploaderip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $messages="";

        $msg="";

        $newID="";

        $FileName="";

        $FileFile="";

        $FileUrl="";

        $FileUrlLink="";

        $FiletnUrl="";

        // check for blocked ip address

        if ($uploaderip != "") {

                $query = "select ip from blocked where ip = '$uploaderip'";

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed.");

                $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);



                if ($num_rows > 0) {

                        $msg= "Your IP address (".$uploaderip.") has been blocked from using this service.";

                }



        }


if ($config[AcceptTerms]=="1"){

if ($tos=="") 

                {

                    $msg= "You must check the box stating you agree to our terms.";

                    echo "<script language='javascript'>parent.upload('".$msg."','".$newID."','".$messages."','".$FileName."','".$FileFile."','".$FileUrl."','".$FileUrlLink."','".$FiletnUrl."','".$page_url."','".$server_url."','".$site_name."','".$HotLink."');</script>";

                }

                }

if($msg=="")
{



// check for a file

for($i=0;$i<=14;$i++)

{

        $err="0";

        $thefile = $_FILES['thefile'.$i];        




        if ($thefile['name']!="") 

                {


        // check for valid file extension

$path_parts = pathinfo($thefile['name']);

$file_ext = strtolower($path_parts['extension']);


        if ($err == "0") 

                {

                        // check for valid file type

                        if (!in_array_nocase($file_ext, $valid_file_ext)) 

                                {

                                        $messages.= "|<em>".$thefile['name']."</em> is not in a valid format (".$valid_mime_types_display.")";



                                        $err="1";

                                }                        

                }


 if ($err == "0") {        
   // check for valid image file
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['thefile0']['tmp_name']);

if(!eregi('image',$imageinfo['mime'])) {

$messages.="|". "Sorry, This is not a valid image file!";
  $err="1";  } }



                if ($err == "0") 

                {        



                     // check for valid file size

                        if ($thefile['size'] > ($max_file_size_b)) 

                                {
                $filesizemb =($thefile['size']/1048576);
                $filesizemb = number_format($filesizemb, 3);

$messages.="Sorry but this image size is ".$filesizemb." MB which is bigger than the max allowed file size of ".$max_file_size_mb." MB.";

                                        $err="1";        

                                }

                }










       // save the file, if no error messages

        if ($err == "0") 

                {


    // replace special chars with  spaces
    $thefile['name'] = eregi_replace("[^a-z0-9.]", " ", $thefile['name']);

    // Replace multiple spaces with one space
    $thefile['name'] = ereg_replace(' +', ' ', $thefile['name']);
    // Replace spaces with underscore
    $thefile['name'] = str_replace(' ', '_', $thefile['name']);
    // Replace hyphens with underscore
    $thefile['name'] = str_replace('-', '_', $thefile['name']);  

    // Replace multiple underscores with one underscore
    $thefile['name'] = ereg_replace('_+', '_', $thefile['name']);


$path_parts = pathinfo($thefile['name']);

// if php < 5.2
              if(!isset($path_parts['filename'])){
                $path_parts['filename'] = substr($path_parts['basename'], 0,strpos($path_parts['basename'],'.'));
              }


$thefile['name'] = strpos($path_parts['filename'], '.');


$thefile['name'] = substr($path_parts['filename'], 0, 22); // limit file name length to 22 chars from the beginning

$thefile['name'] = $thefile['name'] . "." . strtolower($path_parts['extension']);    


    // Generate prefix to add to file name

     $prefix = rand(99,999);

    // Add prefix to file name

    $newFileName = $prefix . $thefile['name'];    



                        // SAVE THE PICTURE


                        $FileName.="|". newImageName($thefile['name']);

                        $FileFile.="|". $server_dir . $newFileName;

                        $newFile = $server_dir . $newFileName;                        

                        $newFileUrl = $url . $newFileName;

                        $FileUrl.="|". $url . $newFileName;

                        $newFileUrlLink = $server_save_directory . $newFileName;

                        $FileUrlLink.="|". $newFileName;


                         if (in_array_nocase($file_ext, $valid_file_ext)) 


                                {

$lx = 3;
if ($file_ext == "jpeg") {
$lx = 4; }

$tnFileName = substr($newFileName, 0, strlen($newFileName) - $lx) . "jpg";
$tnFileName = str_replace('.', '_tn.', $tnFileName);


                                        $tnFile = $server_dir . $tnFileName;

                                        $FiletnUrl.="|". $url . $tnFileName;

                                        $tnFileUrl = $url . $tnFileName;

                                } 

                        else 

                                {

                                        $tnFileName = "";

                                        $tnFile = "";

                                        $tnFileUrl = "";

                                }

                        $filesize = $thefile['size'];

                        $newID = "";

                        if (!@copy($thefile['tmp_name'], $newFile)) 

                                {

                                        $messages.="|". "Please check site settings in admin panel and set proper value for server local path.<br><br>Also please make sure the images folder is chmodded to 0777";

                                } 

                        else 

                                {

                                        // add to database

                                        if($auth_id)        

                                        $uid=$auth_id;

                                        else $uid=0;



                                        //ftpupload($host,$user,$pass,$path."/".$dir."/".$newFileName,$newFileUrl);                                        

                                        //ftpupload

                                        if($no_server=="0")

                                         {

                                        $ftp =& new FTP();

                                        if ($ftp->connect($host)) {

                                            if ($ftp->login($user,$pass)) {

                                                $ftp->chdir($path);

                                                $ftp->put($newFileName,$newFile);

                                            }

                                        }

                        //  unlink($newFile);


                                          }

                                        //ftpupload

                                        $date_add=time();


                                        $query = "INSERT INTO images (prv,ftpid,userid,filename, tn_filename, filepath, ip, filesize,added) VALUES ($prv,$ftpid,$uid,'$newFileName', '$tnFileName', '$url', '$uploaderip', $filesize,$date_add)";



                                        mysql_query($query) or die("Database entry failed.");

                                        $newID.="|". mysql_insert_id();

                                }


                                 if ($file_ext == "jpeg" ||$file_ext == "jpg" || $file_ext == "png" || $file_ext == "gif" || $file_ext == "bmp") 


                                {

                                        if ($file_ext == "jpg") 

                                                {

                                                        $source_id = imagecreatefromjpeg($newFile);

                                                }

                                        if ($file_ext == "jpeg") 

                                                {

                                                        $source_id = imagecreatefromjpeg($newFile);

                                                }                                               

                                        elseif ($file_ext == "png") 

                                                {

                                                        $source_id = imagecreatefrompng($newFile);

                                                } 

                                        elseif ($file_ext == "gif") 

                                                {

                                                        $source_id = imagecreatefromgif($newFile);

                                                }

                                         elseif ($file_ext == "bmp") 

                                                {

                                                        $source_id = ImageCreateFromBMP($newFile);

                                                }

                                        $true_width = imagesx($source_id);

                                        $true_height = imagesy($source_id);





                                }

                }



} 


} 

mysql_close($link);

        // create URL links to display to user



        $showURL1 = false;  // image on hosted page - image only



        $showURL2 = false;  // direct link to file - all



        $showURL3 = false;  // HTML for img - image only



        $showURL4 = false;  // [img][/img] tags - image only



        $showURL5 = false;  // thumbnail pic - image only







        // determine flags



        $showURL2 = true;



        if ($file_ext == "jpg" || $file_ext == "jpeg"|| $file_ext == "gif" || $file_ext == "png" || $file_ext == "bmp") {



                $showURL1 = true;



                $showURL3 = true;



                $showURL4 = true;



        }



        if ($file_ext == "jpg" || $file_ext == "gif" || $file_ext == "png"|| $file_ext == "jpeg" || $file_ext == "bmp") {

                        $showURL5 = true;                        

        }

                    echo "<script language='javascript'>parent.upload('".$msg."','".$newID."','".$messages."','".$FileName."','".$FileFile."','".$FileUrl."','".$FileUrlLink."','".$FiletnUrl."','".$page_url."','".$server_url."','".$site_name."','".$HotLink."');</script>";


}
else
{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>parent.uploaderror('".$msg."');</script>";
    exit;
}



        function newImageName($fname) {



                $timestamp = time();



                $new_image_file_ext = substr($fname, strlen($fname) - 3, strlen($fname));



                if ($new_image_file_ext == "peg") {



                        $ext = ".jpg";



                } else {



                        $ext = "." . $new_image_file_ext;



                }



                $newfilename = randString() . substr($timestamp, strlen(timestamp) - 4, strlen(timestamp)) . $ext;



                return $newfilename;



        }







        function randString() {



                $newstring="";



                while(strlen($newstring) < 3) {



                        $randnum = mt_rand(0,61);



                        if ($randnum < 10) {



                                $newstring .= chr($randnum + 48);



                        } elseif ($randnum < 36) {



                                $newstring .= chr($randnum + 55);



                        } else {



                                $newstring .= chr($randnum + 61);



                        }



                }



                return $newstring;



        }







        function in_array_nocase($item, $array) {



                $item = &strtoupper($item);



                foreach($array as $element) {



                        if ($item == strtoupper($element)) {



                                return true; 



                        }



                }



                return false;



        } 



?>
```

And the upload.js script which takes care of producing the uploaded page:

```
var cp = new cpaint();
cp.set_transfer_mode('get');
cp.set_response_type('xml');
cp.set_debug(1);

function uploaderror(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
function showfile()
{
    var countfld=1;
    countfld=document.getElementById("countfld").value+countfld;
    fld=countfld.length;
    if(fld>14)
    {
    alert("Sorry, i can upload  max 15 files at once.");    
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("f"+fld).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("countfld").value=countfld;
    }

   var file=document.getElementById("f"+fld).value;
   if(file=="")
   {
        msg="Please fill this field.";
        alert(msg);        
        document.getElementById("f"+fld).focus();
        return false;
    }    
}
function showfileux()
{
    var countfld=1;
    countfld=document.getElementById("countfldu").value+countfld;
    fld=countfld.length;
    if(fld>14)
    {
    alert("Sorry, i can upload  max 15 files at once.");    
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("u"+fld).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("countfldu").value=countfld;
    }    
}

function showfileu()
{
    var countfld=1;
    countfld=document.getElementById("countfldu").value+countfld;
    fld=countfld.length;
    fldx=fld-1;
    fldxx=fld.value;
    if(fldxx=="")
{
msg="Email Address cannot be left empty.";
alert(msg);
document.getElementById("u"+fldxx).select();
  document.getElementById("u"+fldxx).focus();
   return false;
}
    if(fld>14)
    {
    alert("Sorry, i can upload  max 15 files at once.");    
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("u"+fld).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("countfldu").value=countfld;
    }    
}

function uploadfile(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id).value==1)
    {
    document.getElementById("showurl").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("showfl").style.display="block";        
    return true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById(id).value==2)
    {
    document.getElementById("showfl").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("showurl").style.display="block";    
    return true;
    }
    document.getElementById("countfldu").value="0";
    document.getElementById("countfld").value="0";


}

function show_loading()
{
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('newupload').submit;
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
       // return true;
}
function show_loading1()
{
        document.getElementById('loading1').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('newupload1').submit;
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
}

function upload(msg,newID,messages,FileName,FileFile,FileUrl,FileUrlLink,FiletnUrl,page_url,server_url,site_name,HotLink)
{
var html='<div id="wrapper"><div style="width:760px;"><center><FONT SIZE="4" COLOR="#00A4B7">Photo Links</FONT></h4><br></center><span class="body"><form name="uploadresults" action="uploademail.php" method="post">';
if(newID)
{    
    html=html+'<input type="hidden" name="idx[]" value="'+newID+'">';
}

if(msg)
    {
        var getmsg = msg.split("|");
        for(i=0;i<getmsg.length;i++)
            {
                if(getmsg[i] && getmsg[i]!="on")
                html=html+'<span style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">'+getmsg[i]+'</span><br>';
            }

    }    
html=html+'<br><center>';    
if(messages)
    {

        var getmessages = messages.split("|");
        for(i=0;i<getmessages.length;i++)
            {
                if(getmessages[i] && getmessages[i]!="on")                
                html=html+'<span style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">'+getmessages[i]+'</span>';
            }
            html=html+'</center>';    
    }    


if(FileName)
    {
        var getFileName = FileName.split("|");
        var getFileFile = FileFile.split("|");
        var getFileUrl = FileUrl.split("|");
        var getFileUrlLink = FileUrlLink.split("|");
        var getFiletnUrl = FiletnUrl.split("|");
        var getHotLink = HotLink.split("|");
                for(i=0;i<getFileName.length;i++)
                        {
                                if(getFileName[i] && getFileName[i]!="on")        {

html=html+'<center><br><a href="view2.php?filename='+getFileUrlLink[i]+'"><img src="'+getFileUrl[i]+'" style="max-width: 550px;"" /></a><br><br>';

html=html+'<strong>Link to add tags and delete the photo <br><div align="center"><textarea name="url1[]" cols="80" rows="1" READONLY onfocus="javascript: this.select()">'+server_url+'/view2.php?filename='+getFileUrlLink[i]+'
```

Let me know what you think is causing this error, as this is the final step I need to fix.

Comment: Please post your scripts in the question, so when `shrib.com` goes down, we can still see your scripts. BTW, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)) and the `center` element also is deprecated. And you have an encoding problem at your main page ("You donâ€™t have to register").

Comment: Unfortunately both scripts are too long to be posted here :/

Furthermore while the mysql functions are deprecated, I am not running PHP 5.5 on this server so I believe for the time being this won't be an issue?

Thanks for pointing out the encoding error - I fixed that.

Comment: I imported your scripts for you, I leave it up to you to remove a lot of whitespace in your PHP script. The `mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained, so there might be security issues not dealt with.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcelKorpel for importing the scripts for me. The whitespace is there just to help make it easier to work with them and code them. I assume neither the whitespace, nor the mysql functions are what is causing the issue with large file sizes?

Comment: No, but I don't know what's causing the issue; I think it might be a setting in php.ini that timeouts the uploading process.

Comment: Weirdly enough the upload does actually go through - but the script seems to stop loading and doesn't load the next page which displays the links.

I have raised the setting in php.ini to allow up to 90mb worth of an upload.

Comment: Try to increase the maximum execution time limit with the function [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Omg. Could you cramp more functionality into a single file? I would seriously consider to refactor this script to be better maintainable. I can see querying the database, resizing, inserting in the database, FTP uploading *and* outputting HTML in a single file. All this will make it very hard to track bugs and 'where' things go wrong as there are *many* things that may cause a timeout or error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issue with creating excel files from large data bases.  What it boils down to is that the PHP script exceeds the servers set time limit.  There are multiple ways to delay/extend this from built in PHP functions, some or all may be used.  I personally had use a combination of the ability with AJAX to allow it run in the backgroun and then redirect that page.

Here is the documentation on how to delay/extend it:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Here is the documentation on how check for a time out as well:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-timeout.php

If you end up going the AJAX route as I did, I highly recommend going the jQuery route instead of vanilla JS.